# How to fit MAX941 macromodel to LTSpice "opamp2"?

Tags: simulation, spice, ltspice

I am new to adding models to LTSpice. I have successfully added [OPA350](http://www.ti.com/product/opa350) from TI, but with [MAX941](http://www.maximintegrated.com/datasheet/index.mvp/id/1220) from Maxim Integrated I get some errors due to the LTSpice "opamp2" model does not have the same amount of pins as the MAX941.

I am not interested in simulation the MAX941 N/C, LATCH and SHUTDOWN pin, which then makes it compatible with the "opamp2" model. My question then is: Is it easy to remove the pins (N/C, LATCH, SHUTDOWN) by editing the .sub file? If so, how?

Here is a link to the MAX941 macro model file:

[MAX941 macro model file](http://www.maximintegrated.com/design/tools/modeling-simulation/spice/comparators/macro/MAX941.FAM)

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to fit a square peg into a round hole. The MAX491 is a comparator, not an opamp. Nevertheless, you should be able to create a "wrapper" model that ties off the unused pins approprirately, rather than modifying the manufacturer's model directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I basically did was use a DIP-8 symbol instead of the opamp2 and it worked.